# Adding self-written jar to Eclipse Plug.In

Tags: jar, eclipse-plugin, osgi

So I am trying to use a method from another project in an Eclipse Plug-In. I have added said project as a jar to a "lib" folder in my Plug-In Project.
In the build.properties' Runtime tab I then used "Add..." in the classpath-menu to add said jar (the library "." is also added as second in the list).
In the build.properties' Build tab i then added the jar to the binary build. When I take a look at the Manifest the jar is also listed in the Bundle-ClassPath.

When I then proceed to implement the logic, autocompletion will provide me with the name of the class I wanted to use from the jar, but it won't show any methods. The only suggestions availabe are "this" and "class", but I need to use a static method (and of course the compiler is giving me a hard time).

My MANIFEST.MF looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: MyView
Bundle-SymbolicName: MyView;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.20170806
Bundle-Vendor: FHDW
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
  org.eclipse.ui
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/TheDesiredJar.jar,
 .
```

I am using Oxygen Release (4.7.0)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`? Which version of Eclipse do you use?

Comment: Editted the Question in accordance to your comment @howlger

Comment: There was no problem with the import but the jar itself.

Comment: Are the methods declared to be `public`?

Comment: Does the *.classpath* file contain the element `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/TheDesiredJar.jar"/>`? Beside non-public (see @greg-449's comment), are the missing methods static (`Foo.` Ctrl+Space) or non-static (`new Foo().` Ctrl+Space)?